# How to remove null from object array in php?

Tags: arrays, object, php-7

I have an arrayof objects like

```
[
 null,
 {
   "list_type": 1,
   "list_item": {
       "id": 21,
       "name":"aaa"
   }
 },
null,
null,
 {
   "list_type": 0,
   "list_item": {
       "id": 24,
       "name":"bbb"
   }
 }
]
```

I want to remove the null values from this. I have used array_filter() but it doesn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"I have used array_filter() but it doesn't work"* Show us, please

Comment: first trim the values using array_map("trim", array_name); and then use array_filter();

Comment: error occurs on using array_map("trim",$listItems);    "
Error: Object of class Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection could not be converted to string"